# Retrieve element with attr instead of setting the attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Using this code: `$('#ipadmenu section').attr('data-order', hash)` I am settings the data-order attribute to the value of "hash". How do I select elements with that attr/value instead of setting the value?

thank you for your help!

P.S. I am using zepto.js and .prop() is not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[With the attribute selector.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

`$("#ipadmenu section[data-order='" + hash + "']")`

Comment: how could I improve that? by selecting a specific node?

Comment: @SnippetSpace added the improvement to the answer, just specify the element ID and be specific with tags. This will minimize the search for elements matching this attribute. (Use this as a general rule of thumb with selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors): `$("#ipadmenu section[data-order='" + hash + "']")`

Comment: That's because I missed the fact that `hash` is a variable, not a constant.